# Updating mysql table with data from another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to update my table called nfl_roster with weekly scores that I have imported into another table (currently called week7_stats for the week I am doing it for now).  For example, in nfl_roster I have all of the players and then empty columns where I will input the scores as the week goes.  Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
Name              week1_points week2_points ..... week7_points

A.J. Green            0             0                 0
Matthew Stafford      0             0                 0
```

Here is an example of the sheet where I have all of the scores for the players for week 7:

```
name                week7_points
Matthew Stafford        3.590
Blake Bortles           2.894
```

So I need to update nfl_roster with weekly scores from another table (in this case week7_stats) and have it UPDATE the score in that week with the column in the weekly table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update nfl_roster 
set week7_points = (
     select week7_points 
     from week7_stats 
     where nfl_roster.Name = week7_points.name
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was backwards, so what I actually ended up using was:
update nfl_roster
set week7_points = (
     select week7_points 
     from week7_stats 
     where nfl_roster.Name = week7_stats.name
)

but I was able to get the gist of it.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to help. I edited the solution for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE nfl_roster JOIN  week7_stats ON nfl_roster.Name=week7_stats.name SET nfl_roster.week7_points=week7_stats.week7_points